# new to jquery - creating multiple spinner controls

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, web-applications

I am working on creating a simple application in php and javascript. One thing I would like to do is use the jquery spinner control for a very large number of input fields (over 100).

the website can be found here: https://www.myweb.ttu.edu/timothsm/alchemy

right now the script is timing out trying to create 100 spinners in the javascript is there a better way to do this? or should i find a different way? (I am only creating a spinner on the first input field for now but the code below is what i was using to do it to all input fields)

here is the code I am using to create the spinners:

```
$(function() {
    $("#ings input.spinner").spinner({
        spin : function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.value > 500) {
                $(this).spinner("value", 500);
                return false;
            } else if (ui.value < 0) {
                $(this).spinner("value", 0);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    $("input.spinner").val(0)
});
```

Comment: On a side note, if you're loading over 100 inputs onto a page, I would seek some assistance from http://ux.stackexchange.com. Additionally, I just ran your code against your page, resulting in all inputs being converted to spinners, and the operation took maybe a second to complete.

Comment: Jonathan, Thank you for your idea of posting to ux.stackexchange.com, I am trying one of the below suggestions about turning the box into a spinner on click.  sometimes it will load in just a second for me as well, but if i have several tabs open or other applications running it can slow down and take up to 8 seconds to load and can cause firefox to become unresponsive. I am just trying to find a smarter way to do this. I am pretty new to web programming and jquery (I am trying out new things to help me learn & sometimes you just need to dig in the weeds for a while to learn important lessons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create spinner on demand. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/aP5hR/6/)

```
var makeSpinner = function() {
    $("#ings").find(".ui-spinner-input").spinner('destroy'); //kill prev if any
    $(this).spinner({ //init new
        min: 0,
        max: 500
    });
}

//process clicks on spinners place holders
$("#ings").on('click', 'input.spinner', makeSpinner);
```

Comment: Very interesting. I might have to give this a try.

Comment: I did try this and it does work, but I have a few questions... Is there a way to do this when using the keyboard as well? When I click on a input box it will turn into a spinner and then clear itself when I click on another, but it does not change if I use the tab key to gain focus. I tried a few different things but they had unexpected results: I tried the "focus" event and it does change when i tab into a box but when i click on the up arrow the box will start spinning all the way to max. I also tried "focusin" to create and "focusout" to destroy but the same thing happened.

Comment: you can ignore my previous message. I got to playing with it some more and I made a typo ("focus" for both instead of focusin and focusout) that was causing issues. I will mark you as answering the question and try to post my code. Thanks again for your great idea.

Comment: `var makeSpinner = function() {$(this).spinner({min : 0,max : 500});}`
`var destroySpinner = function() {$("#ings").find(".ui-spinner-input").spinner('destroy');}`
`//make input a spinner on gaining focus`
`$("#ings").on('focusin', 'input.spinner', makeSpinner);`
`//destroy spinner on loosing focus`
`$("#ings").on('focusout', 'input.spinner', destroySpinner);`

Answer (score 1):

Here are just a few tips. They might not help too much with the performance of what you're trying to do, but they are improvements of your code.

A better way to call the spinner function with a minimum and maximum value is to use the `min` and `max` settings like so:

```
$(function() {
    $("#ings input.spinner").spinner({
        min: 0,
        max: 500
    });
    $("#ings input.spinner").val(0)
});​
```

You should also specify the type attribute for your input tags:

```
<input type="text" class="spinner" id="[your_input_id]" />
```

In the future, with better browser support you will be able to do this just using the html5 `number` input type instead of javascript. Right now it only works in webkit browsers like Chrome:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="500" class="spinner" id="[your_input_id]" />
```

ON a different note, give your elements good self descriptive id and class names.

Rather than this:

```
<div id="ings" class="inglist"> ... </div>
```

Name them this:

```
<div id="ingredients" class="ingredientList"> ... </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I did not know about the min/max variables. I just copied code from the jqueryui.com page on spinners to do the min/max settings in code. I will implement your suggestions. thanks again for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a link to working typing](http://jsfiddle.net/aP5hR/57/)

```
var makeSpinner = function() {
    $("ings").find(".ui-spinner-input").spinner('destroy');
    $(this).spinner({
        min: 0,
        max: 500
    })
    $(this).focus(); } $("#ings").on('click', 'input.spinner', makeSpinner);
```